# How to generate graph from results analysis in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating two clone detection attack on WSN. So I run the simulation with two configuration, the first clone detection app and the second clone detection app. For the two configurations I run the simulation using 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 nodes.

I want to make a graph (Energy consumption in function of node numbers). I did use plot by filtering results by module energyStorage and name residualEnergyCapacity, but I get a graph with energy consumption for each node for each configuration. What I want is a graph where X axe represents number of nodes and Y axe represents the sum of energyconsuption of all nodes.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The OMNeT++ **statistics recording** tool provides [Result Recording and Analysis](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:ana-sim).
However, I think an easier way to plot your graphs would be to export your data to a **CSV file** and sum the Energy consumption of all nodes afterward.